# Why my guessing assembly game not working in sms32v50?

Tags: assembly, x86, mips

I modified an open source guessing game coded in assembly

```
.data #storing data
    startmsg: .asciiz "Pick a number between 1 and 100.\n\n"
    guessmsg: .asciiz "Enter your guess\n"
    tooHigh: .asciiz "Your guess is too high.\n\n"
    tooLow: .asciiz "Your guess is too low.\n\n"
    wingame: .asciiz "You have guessed the number. Well done!\n\n"
.text #start of program

start:
    jal random
    add $t0, $zero, $a0 # store random number $a0 in $t0
    li $v0, 4         # print string
    la $a0, startmsg
    syscall

#######################################
# Main game loop for guessing
guessing:
    la $a0, guessmsg
    li $v0, 4 # print string guessmsg
    syscall




    li $v0, 5 #read int from user
    syscall
        move $t1, $v0 # store input in t1
        #addi $t2, $zero, 1 #t2 = 1 (guess min)
    beq $t0, $t1, win # if stored int = user input, user won
    addi $s0, $s0, -1 # guess used, subtract
    blt $t0, $t1, goLower # if stored int < user input, guess is too high

    # otherwise, guess is too low
    la $a0, tooLow
    li $v0, 4 # print string tooLow
        syscall

    # loop guessing
    j guessing

#######################################
# goLower: Procedure if the user guess too high
goLower:
    la $a0, tooHigh
    li $v0, 4 # print tooHigh
    syscall
    # loop back to get another guess
    j guessing

#######################################
# User won, print win and restart
win:
    la $a0, wingame
    li $v0, 4 #print string wingame
    syscall
    j start


#############################################
# LEAF PROCEDURE
# random: generate a rand number between 0 - 100
random: 
    li $v0, 42        # SERVICE 41 for a rand int
    #addi $a0, $zero, 0 # random number >= 0
    addi $a1, $zero, 100 #random number < 100
    #xor $a0, $a0, $a0  # Select random generator 0
    syscall            # Generate random int (returns in $a0)
    jr $ra
```

in Mars4_5 (jar) works fine, but in Microprocessor Simulator for Students (sms32v50) it say

> expected a comment, label or machine instruction. Got .Data.

[image]

I don't know what's wrong

This is an example of working code in that simulator

```
; ---------------------------------------------------------------
; A program to demonstrate MOV commands. Mov is short for move.
; ---------------------------------------------------------------
    CLO     ; Close unwanted windows.
; ===== IMMEDIATE MOVES =====
    MOV AL,15   ; Copy 15 HEX into the AL register
    MOV BL,40   ; Copy 40 HEX into the BL register
    MOV CL,50   ; Copy 50 HEX into the CL register
    MOV DL,60   ; Copy 60 HEX into the DL register
Foo:
    INC AL      ; Increment AL for no particular reason.

; ===== INDIRECT MOVES =====
    MOV [A0],AL ; Copy value in AL to RAM location [40]
    MOV BL,[40] ; Copy value in RAM location [A0] into BL

; ===== REGISTER INDIRECT MOVES =====
    MOV [CL],AL ; Copy the value in AL to the RAM
            ; location that CL points to.
    MOV BL,[CL] ; Copy the RAM location that CL points
            ; to into the BL register.

    JMP Foo     ; PRESS ESCAPE TO STOP THE PROGRAM

    END
; ---------------------------------------------------------------
    TASK
    ====
    Look up the ASCII codes of the letters in H,E,L,L,O and move 
    these ASCII codes to RAM addresses [C0], [C1], [C2], [C3] 
    and [C4]. Run the program and watch how the text appears on 
    the simulated VDU display. This is very much the same as what 
    happens in the IBM PC running MS DOS. The program you write 
    should work but if you continue to study low level programming, 
    you will find much more efficient and flexible ways of solving 
    this problem.
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: sms32v50 does not speak MIPS. From the [manual](http://www.softwareforeducation.com/sms32v50/sms32v50_manual/010who.htm): "This simulator emulates an eight bit CPU that is similar to the low eight bits of the 80x86 family of chips."

Comment: @RuudHelderman thank you for the help, can you please tell me how can i convert my code to make it work?